# How do I include symbols in regular expression constructors?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want the following regular expression:

```
 /(ending)$/
```

Where ending is a variable. I discovered that to use variables with regular expressions I must use regular expression constructors. So I tried:

```
var pattern = new RegExp((ending)$);
```

But this does not work either! This works if I do not include the grouping parenthesis and dollar sign, but I need those special characters as part of my pattern!

I tried to wrap the special characters in quotations, and also cancel them out by using a backslash, but nothing seems to work! What should I do to include special characters in my regular expression constructor?!

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_7__Octal_and_hexadecimal_escapes.html

Comment: Yeah, I tried backslashes

Comment: You have to build a **string** to use the RegExp constructor.

Comment: Great, I figured it out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't notice the $ and assumed a string variable. doh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it takes a string...

```
var pattern = new RegExp("(" + ending+ ")$");
```